# qt - undefined reference to `_imp___Z*misc*googleDNS*'

Tags: c++, qt

Good day all

*Please note : C++ newbie here*

**Background Info:**

I have been trying to create a set of libraries, where a few libraries use each other.

In this particular case, I have to DLL libraries added as external libraries.

**Problem:**

Error reads:

> netman.cpp:65: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4misc9googleDNSE'

Code in main library:

**//netmap.cpp - Partial**

```
//...
QHostAddress serverIP = QHostAddress(misc().googleDNS);
//...
```

**//Misc.h - Partial**

```
#ifndef MISC_H
#define MISC_H

#include "misc_global.h"

#include <QString>
#include <QList>


class MISCSHARED_EXPORT misc
{
public:
    misc();
    ~misc();

    //Network related
    static QString googleDNS;

    //Command Codes
    static QString CMD_AUTH;
    static QString CMD_REQ;

    struct User_Settings{
    //...
};
```

**//misc.cpp - Partial**

```
#include "misc.h"

misc::misc(){

    //Network related
    QString googleDNS = QString("8.8.8.8");

    //Command Codes
    QString CMD_AUTH = QStringLiteral("AUTH");
    QString CMD_REQ = QStringLiteral("REQ");

    //Request Codes
    QString REQ_USER_INFO = QStringLiteral("USER_INFO");
    QString REQ_VPN_DATA = QStringLiteral("VPN_DATA");
    QString REQ_VPN_UP = QStringLiteral("VPN_UP");

    //...
}
```

*Note : If I you might question the reason for `misc().googleDNS`, I am using this "method" for declaring and instantiating static strings.*

**What is/could be causing this "_imp__" error?**

Help would be appreciated!

*If more info is required, please leave a comment, I will update and add*

**_________________________________________________________________________**

**ANSWER/Solution**

First off, thank you to @SomeProgrammingDude for providing the solution.

**//misc.h**

```
#ifndef MISC_H
#define MISC_H

#include "misc_global.h"

#include <QString>
#include <QList>

namespace Misc {

    //Network related
    QString googleDNS = QString("8.8.8.8");

    //Command Codes
    QString CMD_AUTH = QString("AUTH");
    QString CMD_REQ = QString("REQ");

    //Request Codes
    QString REQ_USER_INFO = QString("USER_INFO");
    QString REQ_VPN_DATA = QString("VPN_DATA");
    QString REQ_VPN_UP = QString("VPN_UP");

    class MISCSHARED_EXPORT misc
    {
    public:
        misc();
        ~misc();

        //...

    };

    //...
}
#endif // MISC_H
```

**//misc.cpp**

```
#include "misc.h"

using namespace Misc;

misc::misc(){}

misc::~misc(){}

//...
```

Rebuilding this by running qmake, then rebuilding, and proceeding to "main" library - `netman`.

**//netman.h**

```
//...
#include "misc.h"
#include "gen.h"

using namespace Misc;

class NETMANSHARED_EXPORT netman
{

public:
    netman();
    netman(QString hostname);
//...
};

#endif // NETMAN_H
```

**//netman.cpp**

```
#include "netman.h"

using namespace Misc;

netman::netman(){
}
```

then one can use one of 2 methods, very similar:

```
//...
QHostAddress serverIP = QHostAddress(googleDNS);
//...
```

or

```
//...
QHostAddress serverIP = QHostAddress(Misc::googleDNS);
//...
```

but the latter is preferred.

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Unless you create an instance of the `misc` class, the constructor will not be called.
2. In the constructor you define the variables as *local* variables. The `static` member variables are not defined at all.

To solve the problem I first suggest you use a `namespace` instead of a class. A class with only public and static members is no better than just a simple `namespace` (I sidestep the whole issue about global variables).

Then you need to *define* the variables, which you need to do outside of any function. Directly in the file do:

```
QString misc::googleDNS = QString("8.8.8.8");
```

---

To put it together, you need two files.

First the header file:

```
#ifndef MISC_H
#define MISC_H

#include "misc_global.h"

#include <QString>
#include <QList>

namespace misc
{
    //Network related
    MISCSHARED_EXPORT QString googleDNS;

    // etc...
}

#endif
```

Then have the source file:

```
#include "mish.h"

namespace misc
{
    QString googleDNS = QString("8.8.8.8");

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will emmend my solution as a question update. May I ask, what "clue" helped you find a solution to my problem - sorry if it seems like a stupid question - since this logic will help me resolve further issues, hopefully!

Comment: @KGCybeX The "clue" was simply seeing the definition inside the constructor.